# How to specify block size for vFAT file system?

Tags: filesystems, mkfs, vfat

I just read that vFAT support different block size at ([this link](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=1031940) and in other places. It should be 512 bytes to 32 kb range ). So how can I specify this option in mkfs.vfat tool? Or does mkfs.vfat support only 4 kB block size alike to JFS?

Answer (score 3):

```
mkfs.vfat -s 64 /dev/scd1
```

Suppose you want to format with 64 sector per cluster, yes you can do it with above command. /dev/scd1  is relative to your device.